# Pack node.js files inside fatJar

Tags: java, node.js, jar

I have a Spring boot project that also executes a node.js file at one point. My project structure is:

```
ROOT
 - src/
 - jsModules/
 - script.js
```

At one point, I execute the `script.js` (with some parameters) from the java code using:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executingScriptString);
```

Once I pack that into a fatJar i have to manually copy-paste the jsModules folder and the script.js to be in the folder root where the .jar is.

Is it maybe somehow possible to pack all the JS files into the fatJar so once I pack it up, I don't need to worry about JS files being copied.

I tried searching how to do this but didn't come across any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

Place the JS file inside the resources folder which makes it available on the classpath.

When executing the script make sure to adjust the path of the file. In my case it would be: 
`node src/main/resources/script.js`.

Instead of the `"/"` symbol I'm using `File.separator` from `java.io` package and seems to be working correctly although on Windows it creates a string of `node src\main\resources\pptrSoccer.js`.

Hope it helps someone.

EDIT:
I tried using ResourceLoader (from Spring framework)

```
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:script.js").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

It works while it's exploded (running from IDE) but when I pack to a fatJar it doesn't work.